# T-SQL - DISTINCT and COUNT from Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables - cut down as follows

**_permissions**

```
project_id | project_name | something_else
------------------------------------------
19         | name here    | lksdjlskdfj
19         | name here    | dflkdkglfkg
19         | name here    | lksdjlskdfj
20         | name here!!  | dflkdkglfkg
```

**workbooks**

```
project_id | name
-----------------
19         | A
19         | B
19         | C
20         | D
20         | E
```

I would like the result set from a query to be

**result**

```
project_id | project_name | count
------------------------------------------
19         | name here    | 3
20         | name here!!  | 2
```

This is the closest I have got but no to avail. Please advise! In the above example, it spits out counts of 9 and 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.project_id,p.project_name,count(w.project_id)
FROM _permissions as p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN workbooks AS w
        ON p.project_id = w.project_id
GROUP BY p.project_id,p.project_name
ORDER BY p.project_name
```

I would prefer to use `JOINs` if possible for performance purposes

There is a projects table with the only useful column being ID

**projects**

```
id | name
----------------
19 | name here  
20 | name here!!
```

Comment: you do not have a projects table, do you? If not why don't you normalise your database and create a projects table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a good design for your tables. You should have a `projects` table that has the names of each project, and only one project per row. Anyway, you could do something like this with your current design:

```
SELECT  w.project_id,
        p.project_name,
        w.[count]
FROM (  SELECT project_id, COUNT(*) [count]
        FROM workbooks
        GROUP BY project_id) w
INNER JOIN (SELECT project_id, MIN(project_name) project_name
            FROM _permissions
            GROUP BY project_id) p
    ON w.project_id = p.project_id
```

With a `projects` table, then the query should be:

```
SELECT  w.project_id,
        p.project_name,
        w.[count]
FROM (  SELECT project_id, COUNT(*) [count]
        FROM workbooks
        GROUP BY project_id) w
INNER JOIN projects p
    ON w.project_id = p.project_id
```

Comment: I need to reference the _permissions table as it contains all the permissions for each project/workbook (and everything else), but your first one works well!

Answer (score -1):

you may want this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.project_id,p.project_name,count(distinct w.name)
FROM _permissions as p
    JOIN workbooks AS w
        ON p.project_id = w.project_id
GROUP BY p.project_id,p.project_name
ORDER BY p.project_name
```

work only if w.name is different.